# How to stretch icon to fill the button in Android tab bar?

Tags: android, tabs

I add the image as icon on tab when i use tab bar. But it is so small. I want it to stretch to fill whole the button. Is there a way to do that?
Here is the Snapshot of my app:
[Snapshot of my app](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4sev2hyv1xo83up/Snapshot_2013-01-09_171805.png)

(Sorry, I am newbie so don't have enough reputation to post image, you can use this link insteed!)
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: your link is not working

Comment: Sorry! I repost the link! [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4sev2hyv1xo83up/Snapshot_2013-01-09_171805.png)

Comment: read the link from my answer below. And also you shouldn't use a tabs on the bottom of your activity

Comment: I am a newbie from android, I know the icon pixel and dpi but all i want is to stretch the icon to fill all the button and can you tell me why i shouldn't use a tab on bottom of my activity? Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a good reading on the action bar design guidelines.
It shows the correct icon sizes to use:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html

Comment: I have just read it. As i mention, i want it to stretch to fill all the button, the icon is only a part of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following link and study about action bar 
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html

Comment: I have just read it. As i mention, i want it to stretch to fill all the button, the icon is only a part of the button.